# fa-star (&#xf005) is always yellow, how to make it white?

Tags: css, colors, font-awesome, font-awesome-3.2

setting `color:white;` or even using the class `icon-light` or `icon-white` makes all font-awesome-icons white, except for `fa-star` which remains yellow no matter what I do!

I've tried overriding css with methods as desperate as using `!important` in an inline-styling on the element. the star remains yellow! (see image below)

Why is this, and how do I make it white?

(Using font-awesome 3.2.1 in order to support IE7, don't ask me why)
[image]

essentially this is my markup:

```
<i class="icon-white icon-star" style="color:white;"></i>
```

Or as it stands when I took the screenprint bellow:

```
<i class="icon-light icon-star" style="color:white !important;"></i>
```

as can be seen in the image, this inline-style rule essentially overrides a bunch of other css-rules saying the same thing; `color` should be `white`.

whats extra-funny about this behaviour is that chromes debugger under "Computed Styles" actually claims that the star IS white. which as you can see is not the case.

EDIT: I actually managed to solve this, but I have no idea why my solution works, so I'll leave the question open in hope someone might provide insight into what is actually going on here. Here's what I did:

If you look into font-awesome.css you'll find the following block:

```
.icon-star:before{
content:"\f005";
}
```

As a first step in my continued research of this mysterious error, I changed the class on my `<i>` to `white-star` and added the following to my stylesheet:

```
 .white-star:before{
 content:"\f005";
}
```

from there I was going to experiment with some other things when I to my surprise noticed that the star was white!

This is no longer an issue in need of solving, But I really would like to know whats going on here, so I'll just leave the question open in hope that someone might provide some insight (for me and the community).

Comment: Can you show the code? The yellow color in hover or always time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. And of course the solution was obvious!

The Color for icon-star is set on the `.icon-star:before` element. What I was doing wrong here was setting color rules to the `.icon-star` element. Colors are of course inherited, but inheritance does not override rules set directly to child-elements(doh!). This is why adding `!important` had no effect.

Moral is: When styling FA-icons, set styles to the pseudo-element, not the parent!

Answer (score 1):

The yellow is because it's a bitmap emoji. To get a vector (colorless) symbol you need to suffix the character with `UNICODE VARIATION SELECTOR-15` which forces rendering to vector. This is documented here: http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/

`VARIATION SELECTOR-15` is `U+FE0E`.

Comment: While that didn't actually resolve my problem, it was an interesting read, and I did get the feeling it SHOULD have solved my problem. Upvote earned. =)

Comment: actually I added a new class and gave it the exact same rule as the font-awesome one, namely content:"\f005"; and it suddenly turned white! I have no idea why, my best guess is that there is some internal rule somewhere in F-A 3.2.1 which made it yellow, and also somehow is impossible to override, which is a ridiculous idea. I'm confused.

Comment: @AndersMartini Yes, it looks like I'm wrong. I tried it locally and Chrome 42 on Windows 10 Technical Preview always gives me the vector rendering. Weird.